# Ошибка при вызове class в xml файле

Tags: android, android-xml

Добавил себе библиотеку `implementation 'com.ashokvarma.android:bottom-navigation-bar:2.2.0'`, захотел посмотреть содержание файлов, в xml файле ссылаются на  `com.ashokvarma.bottomnavigation.BadgeTextView` и у них всё работает. Ради интереса скопировал содержание файла `BadgeTextView` себе и попробовал сослаться в своём xml файле, но он как будто его не видит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Содержание файлов идентично, подскажите в чём проблема?

`BadgeTextView`

```
@SuppressLint("Instantiatable")
class BadgeTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

    private ShapeBadgeItem mShapeBadgeItem;

    private boolean mAreDimensOverridden;
    private int mDesiredWidth = 100;
    private int mDesiredHeight = 100;

    public BadgeTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public BadgeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public BadgeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        // method stub
    }

    /**
     * clear's all previous set values
     */
    void clearPrevious() {
        mAreDimensOverridden = false;
        mShapeBadgeItem = null;
    }

    /**
     * @param shapeBadgeItem that can draw on top of the this view
     */
    void setShapeBadgeItem(ShapeBadgeItem shapeBadgeItem) {
        mShapeBadgeItem = shapeBadgeItem;
    }

    /**
     * if width and height of the view needs to be changed
     *
     * @param width new width that needs to be set
     * @param height new height that needs to be set
     */
    void setDimens(int width, int height) {
        mAreDimensOverridden = true;
        mDesiredWidth = width;
        mDesiredHeight = height;
        requestLayout();
    }

    /**
     * invalidate's view so badgeItem can draw again
     */
    void recallOnDraw() {
        invalidate();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (mShapeBadgeItem != null) {
            mShapeBadgeItem.draw(canvas);
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if (mAreDimensOverridden) {
            int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
            int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
            int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
            int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

            int width;
            int height;

            //Measure Width
            switch (widthMode) {
                case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                    //Must be this size
                    width = widthSize;
                    break;
                case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
                    //Can't be bigger than...
                    width = Math.min(mDesiredWidth, widthSize);
                    break;
                case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
                default:
                    //Be whatever you want
                    width = mDesiredWidth;
                    break;
            }

            //Measure Height
            switch (heightMode) {
                case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
                    //Must be this size
                    height = heightSize;
                    break;
                case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:
                    //Can't be bigger than...
                    height = Math.min(mDesiredHeight, heightSize);
                    break;
                case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:
                default:
                    //Be whatever you want
                    height = mDesiredHeight;
                    break;
            }

            //MUST CALL THIS
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Он же у вас не публичный и к тому же похоже(судя по полному имени) вложен в другой класс - соответственно ui-фреймворк не может создать его экземпляр.
Вынесите этот класс в отдельный java-файл и добавьте модификатор `public`

**P.S.** В библиотеке класс тоже не публичный. Но инфлейтер, разбирая файл разметки, создаёт экземпляры классов через рефлексию - поэтому такой код можно скомпилировать и он даже будет работать, но лучше так не делать - можно получить неожиданную ошибку и потом долго и нудно искать причину.